# How to provide user input to java code during Debug mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to develop some code in Java. I tried a simple code as shown below :

```
    int no_friends;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter values");
    no_friends = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Value entered is : " + no_friends);
```

I placed a breakpoint on the sc.nextInt() line and the debugger successfully stopped this line. However, I did not find a way to give an input to the program while it is in debug mode. 
Is there a way to pass user input values to the code during debug mode ?

Comment: Put the breakpoint on the line right after the input and provide the input yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change variable values in the debugger "variables" panel.  Right-click on the variable name (obviously it must be in either local or global scope) and you will see a "Set Value" option to change its value going forward.

See [vscode data inspection and modification](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection).

Answer (score 4):

Replace the part in the `launch.json` with

```
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Debug (Launch)",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "externalTerminal",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "mainClass": "",
    "args": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the console property to "integratedTerminal" in launch.json fixed the issue for  for me.

"console": "integratedTerminal"

Hope that helps.

Comment: Confirming that this works with Java extensions: Language Support (RedHat) & Extension Pack & Test Runner (Microsoft).